# Enqueue Function

Tags: c++, enqueue

In this code rear++ is after allocating an element in a queue i.e, queue[rear] = ele; so the queue elements will start from index -1 where rear position will be -1 . How is this rear++ working after queue[rear]=ele;

```
void enqueue()
{
    int ele;
    if (rear == MAX - 1)
    {
        cout<< "queue overflow" <<endl;
    }
    else
    {
        if (front == -1)
        {
            front = 0;
        }
        cout <<"enter the ele:";
        cin >> ele;
        queue[rear] = ele;
        rear++;
    }
}
```

Comment: The code isn’t complete so we don’t know what it actually is. If it’s -1 then it’s wrong.

Answer (score 0):

From this function, it seems the front of the queue is at index 0.
The elements are added to increasing array positions.
Example: Your queue has 2 elements: 
ele1 at index 0, ele2 at index 1.
You add another element at index 2 (2 equals rear at this point).
You increment rear (rear++) to add the next element later.

As Sami mentioned, index -1 does not exist in C++ arrays.